# Cannot change UIButton title after setAttributedTitle for it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have an `UIButton`, I want to make color for a part of `UIButton` title so I create `NSMutableAttributedString` then `setAttributedTitle` for button.

After that, the color work fine but I can not change the title of `UIButton`

If I don't use `setAttributedTitle` (by comment the line `[self.btnFanLevel setAttributedTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal]);`), the `UIButton` title can change

**Here is the function that I use to change `UIButton` title color and text**

```
-(void)changeFanLevel: (NSString *) fanLevelTitle withColor:(UIColor *) color{
    NSLog(@"fanLevelTitle = %@", fanLevelTitle);
    [self.btnFanLevel setTitle:fanLevelTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSMutableAttributedString *text =
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
     initWithAttributedString: self.btnFanLevel.titleLabel.attributedText];

    NSLog(@"text = %@", self.btnFanLevel.titleLabel.attributedText);

    [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                 value:color
                 range:NSMakeRange(10, 3)];

    [self.btnFanLevel setAttributedTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Did I make something wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I solve my problem by add this line before I set title for `UIButton`

`[self.btnFanLevel setAttributedTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: comment out this method `[self.btnFanLevel setTitle:fanLevelTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: are you sure, this method use for change the Button title

Comment: @CongTran when I comment this line, the Button title will never change to any value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attributedTitle for any given controlState overrides the title for that controlState. So once you have set an attributedTitle for UIControlStateNormal (for example) then setTitle will not appear to make any change for that controlState unless you set the attributedTitle for that controlState to nil.